# Adding persistent storage to Debian live CD

Tags: debian, virtualization

i am using a Windows XP computer where using a USB thumb drive is not possible, so I am using QEMU to run a Debian live CD. However this means that there is no persistent storage, so every change I make there will not be stored.

Can I add persistent storage to the Debian live CD I am using?

Answer (score 3):

If it is an  Debian livecd from http://live.debian.net/, then it is certainly possible.  Simply create a [virtual hard disk image](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Images).  Boot up the VM partition the new virtual disk, and create a filesystem and label it `live-rw`.  See the Debian live manual section about [Persistence](http://live.debian.net/manual/en/html/customizing-run-time-behaviours.html#524) for details about what to do inside the VM.

It might be easier to actually create a virtual hard disk and simply perform an actual install Debian onto it.  Then you will get the real Debian experience.

Comment: "Boot up the VM partition the new virtual disk, and create a filesystem and label it live-rw."

Do you mean I boot the VM partition using the live cd ISO?